# Change in momentum in Impulse of deformation and reformation

Tags: momentum, collision

I was reading some text on coefficient of restitution when I encountered this ,
[image: enter link description here]

[image: enter link description here]
In the following you all would notice that in Impulse of deformation for particle $m_2$ we can see that change in momentum would be $m_2v - m_2u_2 = m_2(v-u_2)$ but what about particle $m_1$. 
When we write change in momentum for $m_1$ it should have been $m_1v-m_1u_1$ ie: $m_1(v-u_1)$ but then why is it written $m_1(u_1-v)$ . The same thing is happening in the Impulse of reformation part. 
I can't seem to identify where I am going wrong in my explanation. So can somebody please give me the right explanation.

Comment: This is cengage right, filthy jee aspirant!

Answer (score 1):

The impulse on $m_1$ is opposite and equal that was on $m_2$ (action and reaction pairs). $J_d$ is the magnitude of impulse so actually $-J_d = m_1(v-u_1)$ implying $J_d = m_1(u_1-v)$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot